# Capture Mouse Event in Application when AxShockwaveFlash Full Screen

Tags: c#, wpf, axshockwaveflash

I have an application which shows Flash Media full screen using AxShockwaveFlash control.

I need to close the Window on a mouse click, however I cannot capture the mouse click when the AxShockwaveFlash control is active.

The Click and MouseDown events do not work.

In my application I've tried using the MouseDown events in the application, Supporting Grid and Control 'host' but none receive notification of the click event.

As other areas of my application handle this event fine, it must be the Flash control.

Code:

```
_flashHost = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();
_axShockwaveFlash = new AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash();
_flashHost.Child = _axShockwaveFlash;

_flashHost.Margin = new Thickness(50, 0, 0, 0);
this.FlashGrid.Children.Add(_flashHost);
_axShockwaveFlash.BeginInit();
_axShockwaveFlash.CreateControl();
_axShockwaveFlash.Menu = false;
_axShockwaveFlash.FlashVars = "start_volume=0";
_axShockwaveFlash.Movie = loadedMediaItem.LocalMediaFile.LocalPath;
_axShockwaveFlash.Play();
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="CorporateScreenSaver.MediaContainerWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Media" Height="421" Width="600" ShowInTaskbar="False" Topmost="True" WindowState="Maximized" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None"  Background="Black"  Loaded="MainWindow_OnLoaded" MouseDown="MainWindow_OnMouseDown" KeyDown="MainWindow_OnKeyDown">
    <Grid Name="MediaGrid">
        <Grid Name="FlashGrid"></Grid>
        <MediaElement Name="MediaViewPort"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

How can I get a capture the click event either by some global hook or a subscription to the AxShockwaveFlash control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the only way I could capture the mouse click was to use the following.

http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/

Worked really well.

```
using MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor;
using MouseKeyboardActivityMonitor.WinApi;
using MouseEventArgs = System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs;

private readonly MouseHookListener _mMouseHookManager;


_mMouseHookManager = new MouseHookListener(new GlobalHooker()) {Enabled = true};
_mMouseHookManager.MouseDown += HookManager_MouseDown;
```